# Batch File that updating file with every new file added to a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a Html File my.html that have links like that:

```
<a href="1.html">1.html</a>
```

How can i make batch script (for windows,BAT file) that each time a new Html file added to the folder the my.html add new line, for example after adding **test.html**:

```
 <a href="test.html">test.html</a><br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)<sup>1</sup> is perfect for such things. You can do:

```
sed "s#\(<a href=.*>.*</a>\)#\1</br>#g" my.html > my_out.html
```

**Short explanation:**
The Sed command looks like this: `s#search_string#replace string#g`

1. The `s` tells Sed to search and replace
2. The `#` is the delimiter for the Sed command (any character can be used for that).
3. The pattern for the search string is the [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) `"<a href=.*>.*</a>"` 
   (*i.e.* any string that starts with `<a href=` followed by `>`, and ends with `</a>`). 
   The pattern is enclosed in escaped parentheses, *i.e.* `\(pattern\)`. That allows Sed to remember the occurence of the string that mathces this pattern as `\1`.
4. The replace string is `\1<br/>`, *i.e.* the search string is replaced by itself with `<br/>` appended at the end.
5. The `g` tells Sed to repeat that for all occurrences of the search string in the file.

Hope that helps!

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Sed has also been ported for Windows (see [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)).</sup>